# Xamarin Dev Env - Switched to Visual Studio 7

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I just switched from Xamarin Studio to Visual Studio 7 for my Mobile Development Environment. (MacOS Env)

I uninstalled Xamarin Studio, but I would like to know if there's something else that I can delete from Xamarin Studio in order to reclaim some disk space. I only have 10GB available right now.

Is there other way to reclaim some more space from my previous Xamarin Studio environment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you look up what is really eating at your disk space using a tool like [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/)? My guess would be Android emulator images as you only need a couple and not all of them.

Comment: https://montemagno.com/cleanup-up-space-xamarin-dev-machine/